# Spring: Idiomatic way to integrate legacy service

Tags: java, spring, service, legacy

In Spring, what is the idiomatic way to integrate an existing legacy service (that must run in its own thread)?

For slight clarification, this is a service that receives messages via UDP from an embedded device, transforms them into POJOs and pushes them into a (local, in-memory) queue. Ideally, I'd like to encapsulate this as a Spring component and have some declarative way of indicating "this component provides messages of this type" and allowing registration of other components as listeners (1:1 would be enough) without reinventing any wheels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answering my own question) Using `ApplicationEvent` wiring seems to be sufficiently declarative for my purposes, so I'm just going with that.